# Multiple audio players pause each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I hope you can help me with this one. I have a page with multiple audio players, based on this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/wofava/edit?html,css,js,output

Everything works fine, except for the fact that the buttons play/pause *all* of the tracks, instead of pausing one and playing the other.

Obviously, the problem is here:

```
$pp.click(function() {
return AUDIO[AUDIO.paused?'play':'pause']();
```

Now, I could assign separate IDs for each track, but since there will be like a dozen of them, I figure there must be a simpler way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the *audio* element affected for the corresponding "playpause" *div* in this way:

```
$pp.click(function() {
    $audio = $('audio', $(this).parent())[0];
    $audio[$audio.paused?'play':'pause']();
});
```

Basically, you look for the *audio* element that is in the context of the parent of `$(this)`.

`$(this)` refers to the clicked object (the "playpause" *div*). Its parent is the *div* container (`<div class="player">`) that wraps both the *audio* element and "playpause".

The problem is that your "progress" *function* is also selecting the elements by class, so you will need to adapt it in the same way to make it work. Anyway, to check out this solution, just add the standar controls to your videos:

```
<audio controls ...
```

You will see how just one of them play/pause.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Omg, it works now! I added `$this_progress = $('audio', $(this).parent());` for the progress like you sad, and the buttons now work separately.

Thanks a lot!